# Scroll multiple DIVs using Javascript Scrollbars

Tags: javascript, html, scroll, scrollbar

I have the following setting: http://jsfiddle.net/dobbylan/DnmvR/5/

In this example, scrolling the maindiv also scrolls the upper/left div.

However I'd like to exchange the native Scrollbars for Javascript Scrollbars.

I have been searching the web for some **simple** Javascript code that provides a minimalistic Scrollbar **AND** allows for scrolling multiple DIVs.

Any hints on a simple JS code snippet that provides a simple Scrollbar and can scroll multiple DIVs?

Answer (score 0):

If you are willing to use jQuery, I found [a nifty plugin](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller) that will do it for you. It can be styled with CSS, so it can fit the look of your site as well. Check out [the demo](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html) to see for yourself...

A quick look at the source of the demo page also shows you how to use it:

```
$("selector").mCustomScrollbar(
    [direction],
    [easing],
    [easing type],
    [bottom scrolling space],
    [scrollbar adjust],
    [mouse-wheel support],
    [button-scroll support],
    [button-scroll speed]
);
```

Comment: Thanks, however I'd like to avoid using jQuery